# material ui adding onclick

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to add an onClick eventhandler into a material ui example and it is not being called.

```
<Tooltip title="Filter list">
 <IconButton aria-label="Filter list">
  <FilterListIcon/>
   </IconButton onClick={test}>
</Tooltip>

test=()=>{

}
```

Heres the link to the code.
sandbox editor https://codesandbox.io/s/kxq1oqxxjr

Thanks for the help.

Comment: It does work. Try writing `console.log('test');` in your `test` function and adding the `onClick` to the opening tag of `IconButton` instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you add the event handler to the opening tag of `IconButton` and it will work.

```
let EnhancedTableToolbar = props => {
  const { numSelected, classes } = props;

  const test = () => {
    console.log("test");
  };

  return (
    <Tooltip title="Filter list">
      <IconButton aria-label="Filter list" onClick={test}>
        <FilterListIcon />
      </IconButton>
    </Tooltip>
  );
};
```

Comment: it works fine in  sandbox editor but when i copy the exact same code into my editior i get an error saying referenceError: test is not defined and i dont understand why this is happening

Comment: @GreatKhan2016 That's frustrating. I added a `const` before `test` to the answer, which will be needed if `test` is not defined before. Try if it works now.

Comment: Thanks for the help that worked. now i will try and redux state to it :)

Comment: The event handler should not be declared inside an stateless component, it is the equivalent of doing it inside the render method,

Comment: Hello, I have the same code, but it works in chrome but not in firefox.
Do you face the same issue?